# Reporting non-country specific administrative spending in IATI standard

Tags: standards, iati, ict4d, aid

Is there a way to represent Administrative Fund spendings? e.g. organization overhead paying for organization's admin/hr functions at HQ, not allocated to specific countries aid/development projects.

Here is sample of our financial data http://data.mcc.gov/raw/finance/ (filter to Admin Fund).

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to do this is to create a new activity with these classifications:

- recipient-region:

  - code: 998
  - text: Bilateral/unspecified
  - see [IATI regions codelist](http://iatistandard.org/codelists/region/)
- sector:

  - code: 91010
  - text: Administrative costs
  - but maybe have a look to check there's not a more appropriate code: [IATI Sectors codelist](http://iatistandard.org/codelists/sector/)

If there are administrative costs related to a particular project, you could just include that in the description of the transaction.